# Baffled by NaN - HTML CANVAS JS

Tags: javascript, canvas, nan

I'm trying to create a timer within an object - however when trying to increment the counter by the time that's passed I'm getting a NaN error. The error stops if I replace the deltaTime argument with a constant, but then the jump time would vary depending upon the end users machine and work load.

```js
class Actor {
    constructor() {
        this.jumpCounter =  0

        this.jumpTimer = function (deltaTime) {
            console.log(this.jumpCounter);
            this.jumpCounter += deltaTime;
            console.log(deltaTime)
        }
    }
}

let canvas = document.getElementById('gameScreen');
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var lastTime = 0; 

const GAME_WIDTH = 600; 
const GAME_HEIGHT = 600;

actor = new Actor;

function gameLoop(timestamp) {
    let deltaTime = timestamp - lastTime;
    lastTime = timestamp;
   
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(155, 200, 155, 0.3)'
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);

    actor.jumpTimer(deltaTime)
    requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}

gameLoop();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Game Sandbox</title>
    <style>
        #gameScreen {
            border: 1px solid;            
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="gameScreen" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
    <script></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `gameLoop(timestamp)` expects a parameter but you call it without one on initialisation.

Comment: What's the value of `deltaTime` going to be with the first (or two) call of `gameLoop` - regardless of how you fix the missing `timestamp` (pass it `performance.now()`, call it with `requestAnimationFrame()`, pass any other number/zero)?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. Based off the feedback I corrected the issue buy adding [ if (!deltaTime) return; ] to the first line of the method.

Answer (score 0):

As the error resulted from there being on timestamp on the first run through of the code this fixed the issue:

```js
        this.jumpTimer = function (deltaTime) {
            if (!deltaTime) return;    
            console.log(this.jumpCounter);
            this.jumpCounter += deltaTime;
            console.log(deltaTime)
        }
```